# In Objective C, what happens if we pass nil or null to @synchronized() block?

Tags: objective-c

Usually we will pass an object to @synchronized() block for unique reference. for example,

```
+(id)sharedDBHandler
{
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (sDBHandler == nil) {
            sDBHandler = [self new];
        }
    }
    return sDBHandler;
}
```

what happens if we pass nil to it?

Comment: Try it. What happened?

Comment: FYI - the code you posted can't result in `nil` being passed to `@synchronized`.

Comment: FYI - the code you posted is an old and out dated way to create a singleton. Use `dispatch_once` instead. Plenty of examples available.

Comment: `self` in this code is the metaclass that `sharedDBHandler` belongs to, should that be the confusion. It doesn't imply that there has to be an instance of the thing; indeed how should it pick an instance if used in a class method, even if there were some?

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't @synchronize() at all.  No locks taken.  No-op.  Undefined behavior.

Perfectly valid question, btw, regardless of whether the code is antiquated and no longer the correct means of generating a singleton.

From the github repository.  While not a documented claim, breaking this policy would cause compatibility hell.

```
int objc_sync_enter(id obj)
{
    int result = OBJC_SYNC_SUCCESS;

    if (obj) {
        SyncData* data = id2data(obj, ACQUIRE);
        assert(data);
        data->mutex.lock();
    } else {
        // @synchronized(nil) does nothing
        if (DebugNilSync) {
            _objc_inform("NIL SYNC DEBUG: @synchronized(nil); set a breakpoint on objc_sync_nil to debug");
        }
        objc_sync_nil();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Where:

```
BREAKPOINT_FUNCTION(
void objc_sync_nil(void)
);
```

Comment: Why is the question valid? It shows no effort at all. The OP should have tried using `@synchronized` with `nil` before posting the question. The question should have only been posted if the result wasn't clear to them. Simply asking about something like this without trying first isn't appropriate.

Comment: Is this guaranteed behaviour though, or an empirical observation of undefined behaviour? The closest thing I could find was https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html in which the object passed is referred to as a token and a unique identifier, which would imply that `nil` is simply one specific lock, not the absence of a lock. I know experimentally that what you're saying is correct now and, as far as I'm aware, always has been. I just can't find the formal confirmation.

Comment: The first sentence of your answer is badly phrased in my opinion. Which is it? Do we know for sure that it doesn't do anything, or can we simply not make any assumptions since it's marked as undefined behaviour? The two things are mutually exclusive.